# How to sum elements of List<String>

Tags: java, list, sum

I want to sum the *possibilities* (of some characters) in the context of [Shannon-Fano Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano_coding).

#### Example input/output

Given `poss` as a `List` of `String`s filled with *possibilities*.
For example the *possibilities* are as follows:

```
poss = {"0.33333334", "0.2", "0.13333334", "0.13333334", "0.13333334", "0.06666667"}
```

and the `sum` must be `1` (after adding all the *possibilities*).

#### What I already tried

Following code is what I tried. But the problem is that the code does not recognize the possibilities as integers and the code goes to the `catch`:

```java
ArrayList<String> poss = new ArrayList <String>();

private static void ShannonFano(ArrayList<String> poss, Map<Character, Float> m) {
    System.out.println("Possibility for each character in descending order " + poss);
    int sumOfp = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (String element: poss) {
        try {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(element);
            sum += num;
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Element " + element + " in the array is not an integer");
        }

    }
}
```

I tried it also with just a `for` loop, but then I got a `sum` of `0` and I don't know why.

#### My question

How can I treat the *possibilities* as integers in order to calculate the sum of them?

Comment: @hc_dev do you know the application of this algorithm in java??

Comment: @dantsi No you introduced me the term  Do you know, might by compression?

Comment: Is this a [parallel question of you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66101669/sum-last-digits-of-a-list-to-make-shanon-fano-code-java) ? Why?

Comment: @hc_dev  now i m focused to do it step-step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a method the handle parsing exception `getDouble()` and use it in a *for* loop or in a stream:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     double result = poss.stream()
            .map(YourClass::getDouble)
            .reduce(Double::sum)
            .get();
}

private static Double getDouble(final String s) {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(s);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems complicated to a Java beginner, when introducing a streaming solution. Especially without explanation 

Comment: that worked!!  but i really dont understand this method

Comment: @dantsi Maybe Dmitrii can simplify to pre-Java8 (non-streaming). A key here is `double` instead `int` to parse string input to numbers

Answer (score 1):

There are some difficulties that you might encounter, namely:

- parsing the text (`String`) to number
- choosing a suitable class or primitive type to store numbers for your use-case: *possibilities*
- converting from a `List` to an array (of primitive types, like `double`)
- adding numbers (without deviation: use `float` instead the risky `double`)
- reading from the console

Here is my solution, divided into small methods:

```java
class SummingPossibilities {

    static float sumOf(double[] doubles) {
        float sum = 0;
        for(double d : doubles) {
            sum += d;
        }
        
        return sum;
    }
    
    static List<Double> parsePossibilities(String[] formattedNumbers) {
        if(formattedNumbers == null || formattedNumbers.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input must be an non-empty array!");
        }
        
        List<Double> parsed = new ArrayList(formattedNumbers.length);
        for(String s : formattedNumbers) {
            try {
                parsed.add( Double.parseDouble(s) );
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.printf("Could not parse element '%s' as number. Will add 0 to result.\n", s);
                parsed.add(0d);
            }
        }
        
        return parsed;
    }
    
    static String[] readCsvFrom(InputStream input) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
        String line = scanner.nextLine(); 
        
        return line.split(",");
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // read numbers as CSV from console (STDIN)
        System.out.println("Please enter possibilities separated by comma (CSV): ");
        String[] values = readCsvFrom(System.in);
        System.out.println("Read values: " + Arrays.toString(values));
        List<Double> possibilities = parsePossibilities(values);
        System.out.println("Parsed values as numerical possibilities: " + possibilities);
        
        // from List to array
        double[] doubles = new double[possibilities.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < possibilities.size(); i++) {
            doubles[i] = possibilities.get(i); // java 1.5+ style (outboxing)
        }
        
        // summing up
        float sum = sumOf(doubles);
        System.out.println("Result of adding given possibilities: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Try as runnable [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/BVtrdX).

Answer (score 0):

You are already parsing it into integers. Your code works fine. Maybe be you should change the return type to int from void and do return sum at the end.

```
ArrayList<String> poss = new ArrayList<String>();
        poss.add("11");
        poss.add("abs");
        poss.add("11");
        int sum =0;
         for(String element:poss){
             try {
               int num = Integer.parseInt(element); 
               sum += num;
               }
             catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
               System.out.println ("Element " + element + " in the array is not an integer");
             }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: it returns sum=0 for some reason

Comment: @dantsi You shouldn't be using `int`s when your values are floating point (float or double).

Comment: When floating points _less than 1_ given, then `Integer.parse("0.1") == 0` 

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Test{

 public static Optional<Double> stringToDouble(String line) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(Double.parseDouble(line));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
 
 public static void main(String[] args){
   var poss = List.of("0.33333334", "0.2", "0.13333334", "0.13333334", "0.13333334", "0.06666667");

        var reduce = poss.stream()
                .map(Optional::ofNullable)
                .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                .map(Test::stringToDouble)
                .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                .parallel()// if > 1000 elements
                .reduce(0D, Double::sum);
        System.out.println(reduce);
}

}
```

1. to use double.
2. to check for empty or null values, because the world is not perfect.
3. you want a result, not a exception.